# iOS OpenGL ES Analyzer lists "Non-Existent Framebuffer Attachment" and "Missing Framebuffer Attachment", yet the FBO works

Tags: ios, opengl-es, instruments

I'm using an OpenGL framebuffer object (FBO) to implement stencil shadows on iOS. The code works—that is, visually the stencil buffer is doing the job, and performance seems fine.

When I run the application through the OpenGL ES Analyzer instrument, however, it complains of a "Non-Existent Framebuffer Attachment" and "Missing Framebuffer Attachment." I can't make sense of these messages, since the FBO does have attachments for color, depth, and stencil. A call to glCheckFramebufferStatus() returns GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE, indicating no problems.

Is this a bug in Instrument's OpenGL Analyzer?

See also [this thread](https://github.com/isgl3d/isgl3d/issues/20#issuecomment-5044579), which gives no answers, but raises the same issue.

Comment: I've seen the same thing with an FBO that only has a texture backing it, where the Analyzer throws the same error despite the FBO functioning as expected. I'm leaning towards it being a bug, but I haven't completed my own investigation.

Comment: Did you find answer to this?
I am having the same problem here

Comment: @PeeS I never did, and I still have the problem too. It's a right royal pain. One additional bit of info: If I use "OpenGL ES Capture" to view the actual function calls for a frame, the frame buffer referenced by the warning actually seems to have all the right parts. So the cause of the warning is doubly mysterious.

Comment: @OldPeculier This is exactly what is happening to me. I have an offscreen FBO with texture2d attached as color attachment0 and depth-texture2d attached as depth attachment, and i can see everything rendering perfectly OK, capturing frame via ES Capture shows noting suspicious, but Instruments keep saying that bullocks. I have asked apple.com 

https://devforums.apple.com/message/683346#683346

Can't find why is this happening.. Good to know i am not alone ;) Hope we'll track down the cause.

Here are sshots of how it looks like

http://stravaganza.pl/GL/1.png
http://stravaganza.pl/GL/0.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally got an answer from Apple on their Forums:

[APPLE OFFICIAL REPLY](https://devforums.apple.com/message/685479#685479)

> Thanks for reporting this bug. This is a known issue that is fixed in
>   the Xcode 4.4 & 4.5 Developer Previews.   Cheers, Seth.